# Check local file size in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I have this code:

```
func fileSize(url: String?)-> UInt64  {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)


    guard let fileUrl = URL(string:  url!) else {
        print("Problem in converting string to URL @@@@@@@@@@@ \(url)")
        return 0
    }



    let directory = paths[0] + "/" + (fileUrl.path)
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        let attributes = try fileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath: (directory))
        var fileSize = attributes[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64
        let dict = attributes as NSDictionary
        fileSize = dict.fileSize()
        return fileSize
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
        return 0
    }
}
```

This function should delete files from the Docs directory on the mnemonic device.
Unfortunately, it does not work and I get an error message every time:

```
- Problem in converting string to URL @@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Optional ("en / GET_LEAFLETS_PDF / Leaflet new_OK-prev.pdf")
- Problem in converting string to URL @@@@@@@@@@@@@ Optional ("en / GET_TIPS_SLIDES / Golden video of frying ___ 006.jpg")
- Problem in converting string to URL @@@@@@@@@@@@@ Optional ("en / GET_TIPS_SLIDES / Spaces od love ___ 016.jpg")
etc
```

What is the mistake? Does anyone know how to fix it?

****UPDATE****

This is working code:

```
func fileSize(url: String?)-> UInt64  {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

    let pathsFile = paths[0] + "/" + url!
    let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathsFile)

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        let attributes = try fileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath: (fileUrl.path))
        var fileSize = attributes[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64
        let dict = attributes as NSDictionary
        fileSize = dict.fileSize()
        return fileSize
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove spacing from url string. You need to encode the url string

Comment: Sorry. I haven't spaces. I have this: en/GET_TIPS_SLIDES/Quality of software does not satisfy you___bonus.jpg its

Comment: try this URL(fileURLWithPath: url) instant of  URL(string:  url!)

Comment: it's not working :(

Answer (score 1):

All you need is actually:

```
do {
  let fileSize = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: fileURL.path)[FileAttributeKey.size] as? UInt64
  print(fileSize)
} catch {
  print("Failed to calculate size of file \(fileURL.path)")
}
```

where `fileURL` is the URL to your file (eg. `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ID/Documents/file.txt`)

`fileSize` will be a `UInt64` representing the bytes